# Quick survey re: magical sounds

Tags: magical, survey

Your time is greatly appreciated if you could answer this super-fast question for me to help me dislodge my design block I have right now:

What are the first 2 sounds you think of when I say the words "Magical Mystery"?

Comment: "Tour... c'mon..." :D Sorry couldn't resist..

Answer (score 10):

Chimes instantly come to mind

Answer (score 4):

Different kinds of chimes, glass, clay, aluminium

Dust or scattering confetti layers

Clockwork/windup mechanisms/toys

Sparklers, fizzles

Poofs, darker poofs, not comical cartoon ones

Puffs, like powder puff

A musical element, like harp, glock, belltree, tubular bells.. bowed glass works too, as you mentioned, depends on how scary you want to go ;)

Answer (score 2):

+1 for chimes. Other thing that comes to mind are the kinda flash pop things like an old style camera flash burst. The powder igniting for the flashes or whatever it was they used!
Maybe used at the end of a magic trick when something disappears...Kazzam!!! "pop"

Answer (score 2):

Super cliche belltree.  And reversed cymbal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out. What do you think of bowed glass? Does that fit into the magical/mystical?

Answer (score 2):

I have used eno in a thin metal bowl and rotated the water as the bubbles reverberated off the sides. Very cool sound.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sorry - Google didn't give me a good answer to "what is eno", is it a liquid that bubbles in water?

Comment: Hi, eno is an anti acid powder that comes in bottles or individual packets. You can use any anti-acid powder as they all act the same. 

Answer (score 1):

A harp arpeggio, and wind.

Answer (score 1):

Whispy brass instrument

Answer (score 1):

Musically, I'd say harp...

Answer (score 1):

Delicate glass tinkle.

Answer (score 1):

Heavenly choir / voices and any sort of bells.